# HttpResponseMessage PostAsync doesn't response

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, async-await

I dont get any response using client.PostAsync.
I created button in xamarin forms. It should send to server some sentences(json) and return info about them(again in json).
Button code:

```
private async void button_Analyze_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Request req = new Request()
        {
            UserId = this.UserId,

            Language = Convert.ToString(picker_Language.SelectedItem) + ".",

            Text = Convert.ToString(editor1.Text)
        };
        string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);

        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("s", jsonStr);

        FormUrlEncodedContent form = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(markTextUrl, form).ConfigureAwait(false);
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Answer answ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Answer>(result);
        answersList.Add(answ);

        await DisplayAlert("", " ", "Ok");
    }
```

Controller code:

```
public string MarkText(string s) //работа с запросом из приложения
        {
            Request req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(s);


            if (req != null)
            {
                Models.Request request = new Models.Request()
                {
                    Text = req.Text,
                    Lang = req.Language,
                    UserId = int.Parse(req.UserId)
                };
                AnalyzeRequest(request);   

                Answer answ = new Answer()
                {
                    Language = req.Language,
                    Text = req.Text,
                    Sentences = db.Histories.Last().Text,
                    Labels = db.Histories.Last().Label   
                };

                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(answ);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Problem is this code

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(markTextUrl, form).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

never return response and it doesnt reach controller function. If I wait for this code to complete Ill get System.OperationCanceledExeption:"The operation was canceled"

Comment: Are you sure `markTextUrl` is pointing to the correct locahost URL and port that your controller code is running on?

Comment: yes private readonly string markTextUrl = "http://192.168.1.244/Home/MarkText";

Comment: Try prefixing markTextUrl with http://

Comment: http:// didnt help

Comment: Well you `markTextUrl` doesn't have a port and it seems like your just timing out

Comment: You can use Fiddler to see what's being sent and received.

Comment: You definately use wrong URL to send request. System.OperationCanceledExeption:"The operation was canceled" usually marks that connection with URL can't be established. So please check your URL very carefully. Also check your phone internet connection.